# Using AVERAGEIF() over a range of years

Tags: microsoft-excel, lookup, conditional-statements

I have a dataset that includes year, country, and population data. A small condensed sample is below.

I am trying to write an excel statement that would calculate the average population from 1980 - 1985 depending on the country. There are only two in the sample chart but the dataset includes over 145 unique countries. The Year column repeats a sequence from 1980 - 2014 for each country and I am having trouble deciding which function would be best to solve this problem. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
F5=AVERAGEIFS(C:C,A:A,$E5,B:B,">="&$F$1,B:B,"<="&$F$2)
```

Comment: Thanks Akina I used your format and was able to create a drop down list using the data validation option after I extracted the individual country names "aaa" or "bbb". Then I linked your formula for the average to the drop-down list cell. it was AVERAGEIFS(Population, Country, $Q$9, Year, ">="&$R$11, Year, "<="&$R$12) and it worked like magic. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest a method, popular among professionals, known as Control Break method, which categorizes the data as well as create group Look.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Exercise needs `Helper Column.`
- Put `=1` in Cell `T70`.
- Formula in Cell `T71`, and fill it down.

  `=IF(Q71="",T70,T70+1)`
- Enter this formula in Cell `U70` & fill it down.

`=IF(Q70<>"",AVERAGEIFS($S$70:$S$81,$T$70:$T$81,"="&$T70,$R$70:$R$81, ">="&R$64, $R$70:$R$81, "<="&S$64),"")`

**N.B.**

- Shown method avoids to repeat country name in respected column, which saves time.
- Data looks attractive after printing.
- Later on you may hide Helper Value.

*Adjust Cell references in the formula as needed.*